# How do I get the values from an array?

Tags: php, arrays

I am getting following output-:

```
Array
(
    [read_only] => 
    [revision] => 128
    [bytes] => 0
    [thumb_exists] => 
    [rev] => 80527cbf3f
    [modified] => Tue, 03 Jan 2017 05:09:35 +0000
    [size] => 0 bytes
    [path] => /Unfiled Documents
    [is_dir] => 1
    [modifier] => 
    [root] => dropbox
    [icon] => folder
)
1
```

Script :

```
echo '<pre>', print_r($client->getMetadata('/Unfiled Documents')), '</pre>';
```

How do I access the files and folder inside the `"Unfilled Documents"`.

Comment: Is this your full array?

Comment: This is just a directory in system of dropbox. Inside this all files and folders exits.

Answer (score 1):

First you have to get folder path like:
Please try following solution might work

```
$path  = $client->getMetadata['path'];
$files = scandir($path);

print_r($files);
```

Comment: It returns: Notice: Undefined property: Dropbox\Client::$getMetadata in D:\xampp\htdocs\dropboxapi\index.php on line 15

Warning: scandir(): Directory name cannot be empty in D:\xampp\htdocs\dropboxapi\index.php on line 16

Comment: first you have to store your array in one variable then using that 'path' index you can get path of directory.
actually i don't know your array variable i guess variable

Comment: which variable you print for getting above array?

Comment: I am just executing this command- : echo '<pre>', print_r($client->getMetadata('/Unfiled Documents')), '</pre>';

Answer (score 1):

I access the values now:

```
  $query = 'UR-000001';
    $path = '/Unfiled Documents';
    $filenames = $client->searchFileNames($path, $query, 10, false);
   echo '<pre>', print_r($filenames[0]), '</pre>';
```

And get the following ouput :

```
Array
   (
    [rev] => 83527cbf3f
    [thumb_exists] => 
    [path] => /Unfiled Documents/UR-000001 – PLAN – 123432.pdf.txt
    [is_dir] => 
    [client_mtime] => Mon, 02 Jan 2017 13:20:19 +0000
    [icon] => page_white_text
    [read_only] => 
    [modifier] => 
    [bytes] => 0
    [modified] => Tue, 03 Jan 2017 06:54:54 +0000
    [size] => 0 bytes
    [root] => dropbox
    [mime_type] => text/plain
    [revision] => 131
 )
 1
```